# Can a change, to a hidden input, by jQuery be listened by any event?

Tags: php, jquery, onchange, eventtrigger

Maybe you understand also from the question, I am trying to trigger one change that happens to a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="secret" id="secret" onchange="alert(MSG);" value="0" />
```

Under the hood, I load some data to a div which is also hidden, where loading is done with jQuery, input value changes to 1. And the alert box doesn't show up!!

Loading html:

```
$('.somediv').load('ajax.php?changesecret=yes');
```

Change coming from php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#secret").val(1);
</scipt>
```

Any ideas, how can I trigger this change?

Comment: Are you sure the input value is being changed correctly by the code you're loading?

Comment: Yes man thanks to firebug I can see that change happening.

Answer (score 1):

How about manually triggering the event after changing the value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#secret").val(1).trigger('change');
</scipt>
```

Comment: Thanks also for your answer but :S

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it all in the javascript like this:

```
$.get('ajax.php',
    {
        changesecret: 'yes'
    },
    function (data) // This gets the data back from ajax.php
    {
        $('.somediv').html(data);
        alert(MSG);
    }
);
```

Comment: Tom, I need solution for the matter not alternatives.
Thanks a lot for your try :)

Answer (score 0):

Any change to an input done via jQuery code wont trigger the `change` event unless you trigger it as well manually. Try these:

```
   $("#secret").val(1).trigger('change');
```

or

```
   $("#secret").val(1).change();
```

Excerpt from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> If the field loses focus without the contents having changed, though,
>   the event is not triggered. To trigger the event manually, apply
>   .change() without arguments:
>
> ```
> $('#other').click(function() {
>   $('.target').change();
> });
> ```

Comment: Nope man, didn't do it still :S.
Because the change comes from a loaded html I think the browsers doesn't force events by that way.